# Is there a way to block jenkins build steps based on the result of a pre-build step?

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to perform some verification before build a project. If verification are successful it builds the project, otherwise not. Currently I'm able to do this only creating more jenkins jobs and triggering the last only if the previous works.

Is it possible to replicate this behaviour with a pre-build step?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a conditional build step plug-in: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

You can use it to check arbitrary conditions (like a variable set by your pre-build step) before a build step is executed. Also mind that you can have several subsequent build steps in one projects.

Comment: Conditional build step is used to run steps before or after build. What I'd like to do is to not run the build without failing the job with a pre-step command (which is the only way I find out, but I don't want to make the job fail)